# Give Contributors read access to Wiki - Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

I can't find anywhere something to give Contributors access to the wiki

I've already tried to check the "Permission" tab

EDIT: The image below
[image]

Comment: Hi, Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question? If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Give Contributors read access to Wiki

We could get contributors read permission to access Wiki via configure the wiki permission.

Steps: select the wiki and click the button `Wiki Security`->select the permission group Contributors and ensure the permission **Read** is set to Allow, check the pic below

[image]

In addition, if the Contributors user still cannot access Wiki. Since the Deny permission overrides Allow in the Azure DevOps, we need to enter the user account and check the user personal permission, ensure the **personal permission** is set to **allow**.

**Update1**

According to the pic, you are using code wiki instead of project wiki.

[image]

If you want to configure the code wiki permission, we could configure the repo permission to set up the code wiki permission.

Steps: Open project settings->Repositories->select the Repository and click the tab Permissions->then select the group Contributors and ensure the permission **Read** is set to **allow**.

If the permission is set to deny, check the pic below:

[image]

And we cannot see the wiki in the drop-down list. By the way, by default, all members of the Contributors group can edit and view Wiki pages(both code wiki and project wiki). You could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/manage-readme-wiki-permissions?view=azure-devops) for more details.

In addition, In the Azure DevOps, for most groups and almost all permissions, **Deny overrides Allow**. If a user belongs to two groups, and one of them has a specific permission set to Deny, that user is not able to perform tasks that require that permission even if they belong to a group that has that permission set to Allow. You could check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page#permission-states) for more details.

Comment: I can't find this option... I attached the image to show you in the description

Comment: Hi @GianluccaSchuler, I have updated the answer, please check it and kindly share the result here. I will be here to help you solve the problem. If the answer is helpful, you could [accept it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Hi @GianluccaSchuler, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: That's the thing! Thanks for the answer!