# How to go from "published code as a wiki" back to "provisioned wiki"?

Tags: azure-devops, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

Have read about differences of the two here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/provisioned-vs-published-wiki?view=azure-devops.

Would like to try out code as wiki, however, want to have a backup plan in case I want to switch back to the provisioned one.

Once I have tried the "published code as wiki" does anyone know how to import the contents from a repo backup and make it "provisioned one"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already created a project wiki and add a code wiki, the two wiki's will coexist (see screenshot):

[image: Wikis coexist]

If the Code wiki is not the way to go, you can unpublish it only leaving the project wiki in place.

If the Code wiki *is* the way to go, removing a provisioned (project) wiki doesn't seem to be an option in the UI. Still, there are options to [Delete default project Wiki in Azure DevOps](https://www.sanderh.dev/delete-project-wiki-Azure-DevOps/) using the API.

Comment: Thanks, came to the answer after a more thorough search with screenshot similar to yours:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66534935/give-contributors-read-access-to-wiki-azure-devops

Comment: Also this was helpful: https://www.sanderh.dev/delete-project-wiki-Azure-DevOps/

Comment: That's the link I already had in the answer . Good to see you found an answer!

Comment: Heh, docs on deleting the provisioned wiki was quite easy to find, however, the part which you enlightened me on was the key :)

Answer (score 0):

As another solution said, you can unpublish the Code wiki if you want to keep the project wiki.

If you want to keep *only* the Code wiki then you can download the project wiki as a git repo and replace all content. After having pushed the new content you can delete the (old) Code wiki.

Editing history will be lost but that is hopefully not important to you.

Answer (score 0):

To copy content from a code wiki to a provisioned wiki:

1. Clone the new, provisioned wiki with the [clone button next to the wiki's title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7A4P.png)
2. Put the files from your old code wiki into this new repo
3. Make a commit and push to origin

Refresh the wiki in your browser and you will see the